# Java EE project doesn't see database changes

Tags: java, jpa, glassfish, eclipselink, java-ee-6

I'm making a java ee project for class, and am having some issues with the database. When I load a page, it loads the information from the database correctly. If i modify that information on that page, and refresh, it works correctly. If i have the page open on one machine, and modify it on another machine, it does not work correctly.

~Thanks in advance.

P.S. It seems to have something to do with EclipseLink Caching the results. Could I turn it off?

Comment: You need more specifics about "it does not work correctly".  When you reload the page does it not show changes saved on another machine?  Have you confirmed separately that the changes from the first machine have updated the database?

Comment: Are you committing your transaction? Try modifying data in one page - then close the page, and reopen - it should show your updated information. If not, then check your code to make sure you are issuing a commit at the end of your transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was already thinking that it's about JPA so yes you can turn if off.
Paste this code into your persistence.xml

```
<property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
```

[Read More](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/How_to_disable_the_shared_cache%3F)

Comment: The help URL is http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/How_to_disable_the_shared_cache%3F (Observe the trailing %3F instead of a '?')

Answer (score 2):

As of July 2012 the property name to disable the EclipseLink shared cache has changed to

```
<property name="eclipselink.cache.type.default" value="None"/>
```

This should make Eclipse pick up database schema changes immediately.